# Run a shell script via a symbolic link from the directory containing the script itself

Tags: shell, shell-script, symlink, cwd

My desire is not to change directory then execute. I use a jar file and need to execute that. So I made a very basic shell script to do that.

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar TreeForm.jar
```

Then, I saved it as `TreeForm`, not `TreeForm.sh`. Next, I created a symbolic link as below:

```
ln -s /opt/TreeForm/TreeForm /usr/bin/
chmod +x /opt/TreeForm/TreeForm
```

It is successfully created. However, when I run, I take the error below from JAVA.

> **Error**: Unable to access jarfile TreeForm.jar

So, it seems shell script does not run its own directory or does not look into that, but works in current directory. I don't really want to modify my script file giving full path of `TreeForm.jar`. So I wanted to ask, is there a way to find a file relative to script file without changing the current path or adding path to `PATH` variable? Or is there any variable having the path of script, not the current one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shell will not change to another directory unless you tell it to. If you want your script to execute commands in a different directory, call `cd` from your script.

The path to the script is available as `"$0"`. If the script is a symbolic link, that's the path to the symbolic link. If you want to get the final target of the symbolic link, call [`realpath`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html) (available on most but not all modern unices; it's available on Linux (both GNU and BusyBox), FreeBSD and Solaris 11, but not OSX).

```
cd "$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"
```

`realpath` is a relatively recent addition to GNU coreutils; if your version is too old, you can use `readlink -f` which is older. For non-GNU systems, if `realpath` isn't present then `readlink` may be but it typically only looks through one level of symbolic links, most `readlink` implementations don't have the `-f` option to do the full resolution.

Comment: Working like a charm. The only thing is `realpath` is not built-in in Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks for edit and answer by the way. :)

Comment: @ErayErdin Oh, I forgot `realpath` in GNU coreutils was that recent. You can use `readlink -f` instead.

Comment: Now, it is perfectly fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can derive the director in which the shell script exists from its `$0` parameter.  For example, you might use `dirname`to do this within the script:

```
cd $(dirname "$0")
```

That assumes that your jar-file is in the same directory where the script it.

If you want to reference the script via a symbolic link (and still, assuming that the script and jar-file are in the same directory), you could do this by a more complicated script that would

- find the pathname for `$0` (simple if you use the default `$PATH` lookup), and
- use a program such as `readlink` to read the symbolic link.  That isn't POSIX, but exists on many Linux systems.
- if you don't have `readlink`, it's possible with other workarounds (including reading the output of `ls`).
- however you read the link, `cd` to *that* location.

Further reading:

- [readlink - print resolved symbolic links or canonical file names](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readlink.1.html)

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it did not work. :(

Comment: Well, I debugged it, I printed out `pwd`. Since I created a symlink, it sees the script in `/usr/bin` directory. Is there another solution? :/

Comment: It seems there is no way to get the path of original script. It seems it will always get the path of symlink. So I accept this as valid answer. | Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the symlink
2. Execute : `PATH=$PATH:/opt/TreeForm/` then `export PATH`

To make change persistent add the command from 2nd point to your .bashrc file (in your user home directory). If you want it global (to all users) add it to `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: I limited the solution in question as `without changing the current path or adding path to PATH variable`.